# Bluetooth python handle reconnection automatically

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I made a python program on Raspberry Pi able to connect in classic bluetooth (not BLE) with sensors. To do this, I used socket programming. I can perfectly connect to several sensors simultaneously and exchange data (receive/transmit) between the Raspberry Pi and the sensors.

Overall, the most important lines in my code are the following:

```
import bluetooth
import socket

addr_sensor1 = xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
port_sensor1 = 1

sock_sensor1=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock_sensor1.connect((addr_sensor1, port_sensor1))

sock_sensor1.send("Message\n")

while True : 
    while char != '\n' :
        char = str(sock_sensor1.recv(1).decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
        data = data + char
    print(str(data))
```

The problem I can't solve is when one of the sensors is out of range of the Raspberry Pi, it ends up disconnecting. I would like it if when the sensor is within range of the Raspberry Pi again, the python script is able to automatically reconnect to the sensor.

Do you know of any method to solve this problem? Even another method with other libraries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [BlueDot library](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html) as it has the ability to have a callback on disconnect as shown in this [example](https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/blob/master/examples/server_debug.py)